# Hills, bike, etc. disappear in IE 8

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

The hills and bicycle and all the other nice stuff in the header of the new redesign completely disappear in IE 8:

What it's supposed to look like (Chrome):

[image]

What it looks like in IE 8:

[image]

Comment: [Several](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages) [fixes](http://www.apple.com/imac/) [exist](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/). :)

Comment: Looks like there are two `background-images` applied to `body`. I'm guessing that IE is ignoring the first one (that scenery).

Comment: @StephenTouset I am well aware of browser alternatives, and do not use IE as my primary browser. However, not all cyclists are as technically savvy, and some people are bound by the browser available on their computer, particularly in corporate settings.

Comment: Just ribbing you a bit, man! Don't gotta take it so seriously.

Comment: yes it's caused by multiple backgrounds in css3. IE8 doesn't support it. I'll try to find a work around.

Comment: Hills disappear under IE8??  Finally a reason for me to switch!!

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed, I can repro with IE9 in IE8 mode (via the <kbd>f12</kbd> developer tools).

Comment: I get the same thing in IE9 in Compatiblity View.

Answer (score 2):

We no longer officially support IE8, and this problem doesn't affect the functionality of the site.